# How do I write Makefile to compile c project with bin lib obj subfolders

Tags: c, makefile

This is my project structure

```
build/
  bin/
    z.exe
  lib/ 
    libx.a
    liby.a
    libz.a
  obj/
    x.o
    y.o
    z.o

src/
  module_1/
    x.h
    x.c
  module_2/
    y.h
    y.c
  module_3/
    z.h
    z.c
```

I want to compile my project so that
the build directory has these subfolder (bin, lib, obj)

How do I write Makefile for this? (Spent 2 days cannot figure that out)

`module_3` is the entry point with main function in `z.c`

I want all modules become libraries for later testing them

#### NOTE:

default include in modules is relative to the project directory

src/module_3/z.c

```c
#include "src/module_1/x.h"

...
```